# Anisoptropic filtering and multisampling

Tags: opengl, filtering, textures, opengl-3, multisampling

I'm reading OpenGL Superbible 5th ed. I've come across several terms which although explained in the book are not so clear to me yet.

First is multisampling. I understand that it is used to smooth out polygons and help rendering a better image. What I don't understand is how it differs from anti aliasing.

Second is anisotropic filtering. I know the effect of this type of texture filtering, but I want to know how and when exactly it is used. Possibly a general explanation of the algorithm? I googled it and wikipedia doesn't explain much.

Comment: The Wiki article on aniso is about as detailed as you're going to get. It explains the algorithm used in graphics hardware (the "Implementation" section), as well as other ways to achieve the same effect. What more do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multisampling does not differ from anti-aliasing; it is a type of anti-aliasing. [It is well explained by Shawn Hargreaves here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/04/27/multisampling.aspx)

As for anisotropic filtering I could not explain it [better than this article](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/78546-antialiasing-and-anisotropic-filtering-explained/5). If you can, read it all since it covers Anti-aliasing too !

Comment: Thanks, Both links helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Multisampling doesn't differ from anti-aliasing. Anti-aliasing is a general term for any technique which reduces aliasing in analog-to-digital signal conversions. Multisampling is a *form* of anti-aliasing.

I'll leave the Aniso part for when you answer my comment.

Comment: If they don't differ why is it introduced as a different technique int the book? I did read the implementation part, but I don't understand it. I understand near sampling chooses closes texel, linear sort of averages surrounding texels, MIPmapping stores different levels and can be near or linear. But I don't get how aniso works.

Comment: @AtoMerZ: I can't explain why the Superbible is structured as it is. Just remember that just because it has "bible" in the name doesn't mean it's the divine word of God ;) It's just a book, and a book, like anything else, can be misleading.

Comment: The OpenGL Superbible 5th in general is quite bad in my opinion. "OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide" or "Addison Wesley OpenGL Shading Language" are much better books.